# Accessing localhost:8080 through local network

Tags: macos, lan

I'm developing a Python WSGI website.  I'm running a Paste development server on my Mac (OS X 10.7) on port 8080.  I want to test the website on some other devices and OSs I have connected to the local network (Windows 7 VM, iPad, iPhone, etc.), but am having trouble.

I turned on Web Sharing, and am able to access that (port 80) without a problem on all my devices.  Port 8080 still doesn't work.

An excerpt from my Paste configuration:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 8080
```

The OS X firewall (Settings -> Security -> Firewall) is off.  I have no other firewall software installed.

My network is through a Linksys WRT160N router.  I haven't done much with the settings, so most of them are at their defaults.

I've been Googling all morning, but can't find a solution.

Comment: Or use ssh to open a tunnel and use portforwarding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` will make it listen on the local host only. Change it to your IP address that your router assigns